# custom-set-faces for tabline not working?

Tags: aquamacs, customize-face

I have the following code in my customizations.el file (this is Aquamacs):

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:stipple nil :background "White" :foreground "Black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 130 :width normal :family "menlo"))))
 '(latex-mode-default ((t (:inherit text-mode-default :strike-through nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 140 :width normal :family "Monaco"))))
 '(tabbar-selected ((t (:inherit tabbar-default :background "SkyBlue1" :foreground "gray20" :box (:line-width 3 :color "SkyBlue1")))))
 '(text-mode-default ((t (:inherit autoface-default :stipple nil :background "#eaeaea" :strike-through nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 130 :width normal :family "Monaco")))))
```

The mode defaults for LaTeX and text-mode work properly, but the tabbar-selected default does not. I created this default using the customization screen in Aquamacs, and when I do so and Apply it, the tab in fact turns blue. When I Apply and Save, the line above appears in my customizations.el file, but restarting Aquamacs does not result in blue selected tabs. What am I doing wrong? (Pretty much LISP newbie here.)

Update: I just found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/153123/aquamacs-overrides-my-custom-set-faces-options) article on superuser, which is 13 years old and describes a similar problem, where Aquamacs ignored custom faces. Does anyone know if this problem was ever addressed? (NB: this is an aquamacs question, not an emacs question.)

I am running Aquamacs 3.6 (on Emacs 25.3.50.1) on an Intel Mac with OS 11.7.1 I installed Aquamacs from aquamacs.org.

Comment: Start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, then evaluate only that `custom-set-variables`. Does the problem show up then? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this is just a conflict somewhere in my startup files, b/c when I reopen Aquamacs and look, the tab bar customization has just vanished.

Comment: And also because similarly-structured settings such as `latex-mode-default` are processed properly. How can I figure out if this is even a valid thing to set?